# get point coordinates based on direction and distance (vector)

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, vector, polar-coordinates

[image: get point based on direction and distance]

I need to find the coordinates of the second point. I know the *angle* between the points in radians and I also know the *length* of the vector.

I would really appreciate if someone could point me towards the solution.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what application did you use to draw that image?

Comment: Not to sure by now, but I believe that was Photoshop.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Given ***L*** as the length of the vector and ***Ang*** the angle

```
x2 = x1 + Math.cos(Ang) * L
y2 = y1 + Math.sin(Ang) * L
```

Oops... I just noted the top to bottom orientation of the Y axis...
Konstantin Levin, you will need adapt slightly because the formulas above assume a typical trigonometric coordinates system.  In your case the formulas should be:

```
x2 = x1 + Math.cos(Ang) * L    // unchanged
y2 = y1 - Math.sin(Ang) * L    // minus on the Sin
```

Also (what goes without saying, also goes in one says it...) the reference angle should be such that when y2 == y1 and x2 > x1, Ang should be zero, and it should increase as the second point is moved counter-clockwise around the first one.

Comment: @Rambo coder: thanks for the edits (I was focusing on math not javascript)

Comment: Actually the first version works in my case, the one with `y2 = y1 + Math.sin(Ang) * L`

Comment: @Konstantin, I'm guessing that this probably because the angle is measured in a clock-wise fashion.

Comment: Just to point out that mjv's initial formulae are the describing standard polar coordinates; that may help with other bits of maths.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks a lot :)